# Ancestors in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I am using igraph in R to manage a directed acyclic graph that represents families (there is an edge between v and w iff v is one of w's parents). Is there a simple way in igraph to find all the ancestors, of any degree, of a given vertex? I can of course program it navigating the graph, but I wonder if there is a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: Look at `neighborhood`.

Comment: Or `subcomponent` with `mode="in"` or `mode="out"`, depending on how your edges are oriented (i.e. from parent to child or vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the `local_` set of functions from `tidygraph`. In the example below, I'm counting the number of total ancestors by setting `mode="in"`:

```r
library(tidygraph)
library(dplyr)

edges = tribble(
  ~from, ~to, 
  1, 2,
  3, 2, 
  4, 3, 
  2, 5, 
  5, 6,
  3, 7)

g = tbl_graph(edges = edges) 
plot(g)
```

[image]

```r
g %>%
  activate(nodes) %>% 
  mutate(numAncestors = local_size(order = graph_order(), mode = 'in')) %>%
  as_tibble()

#> # A tibble: 7 x 1
#>   numAncestors
#>          <dbl>
#> 1            1
#> 2            4
#> 3            2
#> 4            1
#> 5            5
#> 6            6
#> 7            3
```

Answer (score -1):

One option is incident, in that case, and having g the igrap graph:

```
incident(g, v, mode=c("in"))
```

where v is the given vertex (index).

"in" is used to find all nodes that go into that vertex, so the parents or ancestors, "out" to find sons all the edges leaving the vertex and "all" if indifferent.

For more info, look at documentation ?incident

Comment: This does not count ancestor edges, just direct parents